# Conditionally load modules in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-route-guards

Is there any way to load module conditionally or prevent module access in some conditions?
I just want to load modules and its subroutes only a specific condition satisfied.

The possible solution I tried till now

1. Lazy load modules with routing details.
2. canActivate with auth mechanism service.

Is there any effective way to achieve the same so that.

1. Common features should not be duplicated.
2. Module with routing details should be only loaded when in need.

Any help in this regard appreciated TIA.

Comment: How is lazy-loading not effective?

Comment: suppose a set of users does need a module 'X' then there is no need to put that module in the app. It should be only loaded into the memory and browser whenever in need.

Comment: That's exactly what lazy-loading, using the router allows. What is the problem?

Comment: In this case, as well we need to put entry-level of module X route to the main router module. i.e 
 path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazyloadmodule.module#LazyloadmoduleModule' can this entry be conditional as well?

Comment: although the user can navigate to <someaddress>/lazy in such cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Like in angular 1.x a module with routing details can be loaded at runtime using some plugin like oclazyload. I just want the similar functionality.

Comment: The router does that. That's what lazy-loading is. If a module is lazy-loaded, then the browser will only load it when the user navigates to one of its routes.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet my problem   is that the files can be loaded by invoking that url itself.
I just want that should only be loaded with route + some BL in place

Comment: What does "some BL" mean? It seems you want to prevent the browser to work like a browser works, or a webapp to work like a webapp works. If the user goes to a URL, it means he wants to go to that URL. If the module matching that URL is lazy-loaded, then angular should load the module, and navigate to the requested route. Why shouldn't it do that? Not doing that would prevent bookmarking the page, refreshing the page, sending the link of tha page in an email, etc.

Comment: do you need a combination of the lazy loading and canActivate? I mean do you want a lazy loaded module which is loaded only in case that some condition is true?

Comment: BL means business logic.
Let assume a case a normal user shouldn't have access to admin module. But if he enter admin url in browser the admin module will be loaded in this case. I.e admin.module.js will be loaded. I just want to prevent this

Comment: @GHB you got me right thanks

Comment: Ah. Then use a CanLoad guard. Not a CanActivate.

Comment: you can do many things. in the routing of main component of your lazy loaded module, you can put a canActivate guard. you can also check your conditions in it's initial level and navigate away if they dont match. and best of all, use a CanLoad guard.

Comment: Thanks @GHB does can load guard prevent loading of module file if condition is not satisfied?

Comment: yes, that's it's purpose. from the docs: "Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a children can be loaded." https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the [CanLoad guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad).

> Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a
>   children can be loaded.